# converting pixel data to image in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

Hi 
  I have data of an image of size 640 * 480 pixels, the data is in the format of 0s and 1s, in a txt file. Therefore there are 640*480=307200 characters (0s and 1s) in a text file. The catch is that  0 means that there was nothing in the original image (say black background) and 1 means there is (say a user is standing and it is pertaining to the user blob) and hence its NOT to be mistaken with RGB or byte data.

I need to read and convert this into an image of size 640*480 pixels in java,where pixels indicated by 0 may be set to one color (say black) and 1 to other (say white).
How do I do it??? thanks for help.

Comment: Read the `txt` file character by character and paint the image accordingly using a if-else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to read it in. If you know it's width, you can do something like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
boolean[][] mask = new boolean[640][480];
int i = -1;
int count = 0;
while((i = in.read()) !- -1) {
    int x = count % 640;
    int y = count / 640;
    mask[x][y] = (i == '1');
    count++;
}
```

Then you can paint like this

```
paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0,0,640,480); // draw the black background

    // mask it with white
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    for(int x = 0; x < 640); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 480); y++) {
            if(mask[x][y]) g.drawRect(x,y,1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou glowcoder, but i am not sure how to use the paint(Graphics g) function..