# Java monochrome .png to .pbi pixel data (bit per pixel, 1=W, 0=B)

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, pebble-watch

Trying to send an image to the Pebble smartwatch, from an Android app. It seems like [this may be applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377786/android-converting-a-bitmap-to-a-monochrome-bitmap-1-bit-per-pixel?rq=1), but the purpose is different and I don't understand enough to know whether it applies to my image and output.

I have an `RGB_565` image courtesy of `BitmapFactory`, that is known to be black & white and known 96x96 size. In order to send it to the Pebble, I need it in their `.pbi` format:

- 1 bit for 1 pixel
- Padded to 32 bits wide (not necessary with 96x96 - hence my choice!)
- 1 => White; 0 => Black

I'm trying:

```
int pbi[][] = new int[96][96];
for (int row = 0; row < 96; row++ ){
    for (int col = 0; col < 96; col++){
        if (bmp.getPixel(row, col) == 0xFFFFFFFF) pbi[row][col] = 1;
        else pbi[row][col] = 0;
    }
}
```

Does this make sense? I can't really test it, as for that I need first to implement the harder next step of transmitting it to the Pebble.. but in order to do that I need this bit-per-pixel format.

Or is there an easier built in method? [Something like this, but in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844024/converting-pixel-data-to-image-in-java?rq=1)? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you mean to check the color not set it in the if statement?  (==  instead of =)

```
i = 144x144
current_pix = find_first()
for i < 0
    if (pix_colour(current_pix) == white) add_binary_weight_to_output(i)
    i -= 1
```

Comment: Yes I do, that's a bad typo. But that's not an answer to the question. Thanks though.